# spring integration: How do I call the Spring Integration from Spring Controller?

Tags: spring, tcp, spring-integration, integration

please, Can you help me?
**All of source here it is.**
(https://github.com/mcvzone/integration-tcp-test.git)

Thank you.

**1. I created a spring integration-tcp-client context xml file.**

```
    <int:gateway id="gw"
                 service-interface="com.example.demo.module.SimpleGateway"
                 default-request-channel="input"/>

    <int-ip:tcp-connection-factory id="client"
                                   type="client"
                                   host="localhost"
                                   port="1234"
                                   single-use="true"
                                   so-timeout="10000"/>

    <int:channel id="input"/>

    <int-ip:tcp-outbound-gateway id="outGateway"
                                 request-channel="input"
                                 reply-channel="clientBytes2StringChannel"
                                 connection-factory="client"
                                 request-timeout="10000"
                                 reply-timeout="10000"/>

    <int:object-to-string-transformer id="clientBytes2String"
                                      input-channel="clientBytes2StringChannel"/>
```

**2. And I created a RestController.**

```
@RestController
public class TcpController {
    
    final GenericXmlApplicationContext context;
    final SimpleGateway simpleGateway;
    
    public TcpController(){
        this.context = new GenericXmlApplicationContext();
        context.load("classpath:META-INF/spring/integration/tcpClientServerDemo-context.xml");
        context.registerShutdownHook();
        context.refresh();
        
        this.simpleGateway = context.getBean(SimpleGateway.class);
    }
    
    @RequestMapping("/tcp/test")
    public String test(String name) {
        //SimpleGateway simpleGateway = context.getBean(SimpleGateway.class);
        String result = simpleGateway.send(name);
        System.out.println("result : " + result);
        return result;
    }

}
```

**3. I start spring boot and open 1234 port (new ServerSocket(1234)) and I call url.(http://localhost:8080/tcp/test)**
**4. It result is error.**

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: unable to determine a Message or payload parameter on method
.
.
.
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy60.send(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at com.example.demo.TcpController.test(TcpController.java:25) ~[classes/:na]
```

Comment: Can you show more stack trace, please?

Comment: Also show the `SimpleGateway` code.

Comment: See my answer with some explanations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has started to work when I changed your code to this:

```
@RequestMapping("/tcp/test")
public String test(@RequestBody String name) {
```

Pay attention to the `@RequestBody` on the method param. By default Spring MVC does not know to what from the request to map into an argument for this param. So, it is left as `null`.

On the other hand, when the argument for that gateway call is `null`, Spring Integration cannot create a `Message<?>` to send because the payload cannot be `null`. Therefore you end up with such an exception.

We probably may revise that exception message to make it more obvious for end-users what is going on. Feel free to raise a GH issue on the matter!

Comment: Here is some fix to make it more clearer: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/pull/3500

Comment: thank you.  github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/pull/3500 is good.